# data type storage in C

Tags: c, memory-management, types

I want to understand how declaring a variable as char saves memory than declaring int or short. I know the fact that declaring char reserves 1 byte in memory while 2 or 4 bytes get reserved for int. So now, suppose in a 16 bit processor, a variable char is stored at say location 0xABCD. Since it is a 16 bit processor, 1 byte or 8 bits of the 16 bits at the address 0xABCD is reserved for char. Now an int variable is stored at location 0xBCDE, accordingly it will reserve 16 bits of the 16 bits available at the location 0xBCDE. So now what I really want to know is what happens to the 8 bits that are at the location 0XABCD left over after reserving memory for char variable considering the fact that at one memory location only one variable can be stored.

Comment: You might be able to find what you need by looking for info on *memory alignment*.

Comment: "Storing a value at memory address `0xABCD`" means *putting that value into a contiguous block of memory starting at `0xABCD`*, it does *not* mean that the entire value can be placed in a single address. "16 bits at the address 0xABCD" is not a correct description, "16 bits **starting** at the address 0xABCD" is better.

Comment: What @DCoder says. That's the reason that most assembly languages have commands to manipulate more than single-byte addresses, like load word, store word, where word is at least 2B.

Comment: If that processor can handle 8 bit and 16 bit values as well, it would probably mean the bytes at 0xBCDE and 0xBCDF are used for that int.

Answer (score 2):

Memory addresses do not work like "variables". They can not store 8 *or* 16 bits, they can *only* and *exclusively* store *exactly* 8 bits (one single byte). (a)

When an int gets stored "at" an address, it takes up more space -- not "in" that *same* address, but flowing over in *next* memory addresses, immediately following "the" memory address. Thus, if you store a `char` at 0xABCD, the compiler knows it's safe to assume a next value can be stored at 0xABCE. If you store a 16-bit `short` at 0xABCD, the compiler knows the data gets stored in 0xABCD *and* 0xABCE.(b)

---

(a) For sake of clarity. There are configurations where a single memory unit can hold more or less bits (historically, the 8th bit was meant for error checking, and so one could only store 7 significant bits of data in each location).

(b) Again, for sake of clarity. A compiler may decide to use 4, or even 8 bytes of memory space for each type of char, short, and int. This is because reading and writing a "native" size value from memory may be faster than "odd" sizes. The "native" size of data is the one a CPU is designed *specifically* for.

Answer (score 1):

If *char* is being stored at adderss 0xABCD, only the **single memory cell**, which size is usually *8 bits or 1 byte*, which is located by address 0xABCD is being used for this variable (let's assume we don't use data structure alignment). So, memory cell 0xABCE (or 0xABCC - it depends on memory architecture) is not being used at all.

Now, for *int*. Actually, ANSI C doesn't say how much memory (cells/bytes) should int use. *Usually*, on 32 bit OSes - it's 32 bits or 4 bytes, on 64 bit OSes - 64 bits or 8 bytes.

It is safe to assume, that on our 16 bit processor int variable will be stored in 16 bits or 2 bytes (2 memory cells): 0xABCD and 0xABCE (or 0xABCC).